# How can I have a Pcomm session automatically log in to a specific connection..?

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We have an AS400 DB2 v7r3m0 system, to which we connect with PComm v6 emulator sessions. For a certain high-throughput printer, there's a stand-alone PC acting as a print server, with a PComm printer session.

I'd like to have that PComm printer session automatically start, make the connection, and log in, so I can have it run from Windows Startup.

I've been able to record & clean up a VBS macro that logs in once the connection is made, but not the connection process. Unless I'm missing something, macros cannot be recorded or run until the connection is made.

Is there a built-in process by which the connection can be made automatically..?

If not, I'm assuming it could be done with autECLConnMgr and related libraries in VBS, but the IBM documentation on that is a little deep for me. If that's the way to go, could someone provide an example..?

EDIT: This is the dialog I speak of. This sometimes precedes the opening of any emulator windows, sometimes from the IBM i control panel applet, and so it cannot be scripted through an emulator window way, and thus my assumption it needs to go through WScript.

[image]

Comment: With a lot of terminal emulators, you can save the session connection details into a specific configuration file, which you can execute to launch the session directly - have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, we regularly make use of saving sessions in the *.WS files, but the connection I speak of precedes that. It's the system login one gets from the menus Communication > Configure > Properties. Also in iNavigator > MyConnections. It presents the `IBM i Signon` dialog. I've added a screenshot to my OP.

Comment: Are you using any of the PComm host class automation libraries?

Comment: Yes, but not yet directly for this problem. I've been experimenting with them in Excel VBA for a password reset utility, and then manually converting the VBA to VBS. That's how I assumed the library would be autECLConnMgr.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you should look into using the Windows scripting language [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to fill in any gaps in functionality that you can't achieve by other means. Virtually anything you can do by hand on a PC can be automated using AutoHotkey, including keyboard and mouse input.

Comment: Why would I settle for a SendKeys type of utility when Pcomm has it's own built-in OOP scripting language with libraries that expose objects for connections, status, screen, fields, and even file transfer..?

Comment: It's not an issue of "settling", nor is it an issue of abandoning PCOMM. For the bulk of your scripting, the PCOMM interface surely is a good option. But you said you're having trouble getting the login to work, and I'm saying it's virtually guaranteed that AutoHotkey can accomplish the login. You can call the AutoHotkey script from whatever other scripting language you're using, and/or put it in the Windows Startup.

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm familiar with AHK; I've used it as an auto-clicker for various things.  But the issue with Pcomm connections is this: VBS macros can only be run in a terminal session after it's connected, but the connection exists before that. So any VBS code pertaining to connections needs to be run outside the terminal window (unless I'm severely misunderstanding something). And the obvious candidate for that is Wscript. But...now that I think about it, that seems to be a *very* big shortcoming. I'm going to dig a little deeper on that, to see if VBS *can* be run before the connection is made.